Average Rank versus Ranked Average in Parameter Estimation
I have the following problem:

In a cricket tournament, the eleven batsmen of a team play 100 matches before the final. The runs scored by each are available. Determine the average rank of the batsmen using the 100 matches, and use this to predict his performance in the final.

(In terms of context, we could replace the batsmen with students sitting for tests, time taken to complete a race, etc, etc).
I can think of two approaches:

Determine the rank of each batsman in each match. Average the ranks.
Determine the total runs scored, and hence find the average runs scored. Use the average runs scored to determine the rank.

Which approach is better? Is there an even better approach. Answers in terms of estimators of a population parameter would be useful.

You may want to think about how the performance of the prediction is scored against the eventual outcome (and in particular how a prediction using approach 1 made up of lots of $5th$ and $6th$ places would score, since that will not be the outcome).
